# Assign the right android fragment on rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, initialization, bottomnavigationview

I've been developing a small Android application lately but I've faced a bug I struggle to solve.

Since i'm using a BottomNavigationView I have to initialize my Home fragment like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    FragmentTransaction f = fm.beginTransaction();
    f.replace(R.id.content, homeFragment).commit();
}
```

the replace happens on this FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Yet this raises a little bug: if I rotate the device the fragment is set back to my homeFragment, regardless of the current one.
Since i cannot call directly my

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
//
}
```

I've tryed some turnarounds:

- I've tryed using a boolean isFragmentInitialized
- I've tryed decentralizing the onNavigation function into an external private setFragment function which checked the selected menu item and applied the according fragment
- I've tryed starting directly with homeFragment rather than with the linear view I am using

But theese solutions brings no luck:
the last one crashes after you turn the screen and select home
the others simply result in the same situation with my standard initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do that will cause your code to run only the first time the user navigates to your `Activity` is to move your code from `onStart()` to `onCreate()` and wrap it inside an `if` statement that checks if `savedInstanceState` is null (which will only be true the first time the activity starts up).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate();
    // the rest of your onCreate() etc...

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        FragmentTransaction f = fm.beginTransaction();
        f.replace(R.id.content, homeFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

You can use this technique for anything that you want to run only the first time your activity starts up, not just with `FragmentTransaction`s. Though fragments are a very common use case for this trick.

Comment: It works greatly!
Thanks for the quick and helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

One way in which you could do this is by creating a variable to store a fragment tag, in the switch case that handles your bottom navigation you could save the appropriate tag in that variable. Then implement the `onSaveInstanceState` function and write that tag to your outstate. Finally, listen for a saved instance state in `onCreate` and launch the appropriate fragment. Something like this:

```
String fragmentTag;
String FRAGMENT-TAG-KEY = "fragment-tag";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // recovering the instance state
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String fragmentTag = savedInstanceState.getString("FRAGMENT-TAG-KEY");
        switch (fragmentTag){
            case "FragmentA": {
                //launch this fragment. 
                break;
            }
            case "FragmentB": {
                //launch this fragment. 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(FRAGMENT-TAG-KEY, fragmentTag);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_home: {
                    fragmentTag = "FragmentA";
                }

                case R.id.action_fragmentb: {
                    fragmentTag = "FragmentA";
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

If it is the case that that particular fragment needs to store data, you could store it locally and reload it. Otherwise you may have to send the data back to the activity and then pass it into your fragment. It may be the case that you can store the instance of your fragment and implement the outstate in the fragment as well, then in `onActivityCreated` in the fragment you can restore your instance state. I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like so I can only speculate on how you might go about storing your fragment's data if it has any.